# Dynamically change the android id of an element

Tags: java, android, appium

Is it possible to change the android id of a view or any of their elements, such as an imageView based on some code? That is, verifying a variable such as a bool and having a different id depending on the value such as `image_true` and `image_false`.

I am working on an automation project with Appium and I need to be able to differentiate a success pop-up from an error pop-up. They are essentially the same component but the image is different depending on the state of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View#setId with some positive integer as ids are basically integers

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not clear enough but it's possible to change it by `#setId` method of View. And consider this issue that changing the view id when runtime may cause errors inside the code if it is using that view by hardcoded id so it can't be found by those components anymore.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to dynamically change tags using View#setTag which can accept strings. To access the view using tags, you can use findViewWithTag.

Sample code to access view using tag:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
TextView textView = layout.findViewWithTag("someTag");
```